# Python string formatting displays issue

Tags: python

Running Python 2.6

I need to make an api call to jenkins using the following format:

`j.build_job('My Job Name', {'BRANCH_NAME': 'xyz', 'VERSION': '12.2' })`

I need to pass in two variables `branch` and `version` but upon displaying the output as a test, it doesn't insert the branch name into the first field.

`('My Job Name', {'BRANCH_NAME': '{0}', 'VERSION': '12.2'})`

Code below:

```
branch="xyz"
version="12.2"

print ('My Job Name', {'BRANCH_NAME': '{0}', 'VERSION': '{1}'.format(branch,version) })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it.

```
branch="xyz"
version="12.2"

print ('My Job Name', {'BRANCH_NAME': '{0}'.format(branch) , 'VERSION': '{0}'.format(version) })
# ('My Job Name', {'BRANCH_NAME': 'xyz', 'VERSION': '12.2'})
```

Or set vars in dict:

```
print ('My Job Name', {'BRANCH_NAME': branch , 'VERSION': version})
# ('My Job Name', {'BRANCH_NAME': 'xyz', 'VERSION': '12.2'})
```

Comment: That did the trick. I did have the vars directly in the dict but it wasn't working. I have no idea what the heck happened but I just tried it again and it works.

Comment: @luckytaxi I just base on your question to solve but I think my answer should satisfy you.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't your string look like this.

```
print ('My Job Name {BRANCH_NAME: {0}, VERSION {1}}'.format(branch,version))
```

Comment: No i need the comma after the branch name

Comment: You can add a comma inbetween it then. It's just a print statement, the point is it shows that the branch/version are getting filled in correctly.